# Bringing a Django Model to a HTML Table

Tags: django, django-views

I am very new to Django and I am working on my first training project.

I want to document every month a set of meters (water, electricity, and more) and I want to see those meters in a html table like:

|  | Nov 2023 | Dec 2023 | Jan 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Meter 1 |  | 500 | 510 |
| Meter 2 | 1000 |  | 1300 |
| Meter 3 | 100 | 110 | 120 |

I am using 4 models in models.py:

model metertype -> electricity, water, and other types of meters

model meter -> name/description of the meter

model readingdate -> date of the reading, normally last day of month

model readingsvalue -> the values I read from the meters

```
from django.db import models


class meterType(models.Model):
    meterType = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   

class meter(models.Model):
    meterName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meterType = models.ForeignKey(
        meterType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        

class readingDate(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    

class readingsValue(models.Model):
    readingsValue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    meter = models.ForeignKey(Zaehler, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    readingDate = models.ForeignKey(Ablesedatum, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

After this done (it seams to work in the admin area). I put up a view.py which is very basic:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import readingsValue, meter, meterType, readingDate


def index(request):
    readingsValue = readingsValue.objects.all()
    meter = meter.objects.all()
    meterType = meterType.objects.all()
    readingDate = readingDate.objects.all()

    return render(request, "meters/index.html",
                  {"meter": meter,
                   "readingsValue": readingsValue,
                   "meterType": meterType,
                   "readingDate": readingDate,
                   })
```

Now I am really lost on how to get the data to the table. I am trying with for loops und if statments but data always gets messed up. I think this is a standard problem, however I did not find any solution until now. How is Django thinking here and how is the formal approach?

This is the html file so far:

```
{% extends 'meters/base.html' %}  

{% block title %}   
  All Data
{% endblock %}  

{% block content %}   
  <table>     
    <tr>       
      <th></th>       
      {% for readingDate in readingDate %}         
        <th scope="col">{{ readingDate.readingDate|date:'M Y' }}</th>       
      {% endfor %}     
    </tr>     
    {% for meter in meter %}       
      <tr>         
        <th scope="row">{{ meater.meaterName }}</th>       
      </tr>     
    {% endfor %}   
  </table> 
{% endblock %}
```

Regards
Georg

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to fetch all of the values separately, readingsValue is connected to the other objects already.

```
def index(request):
    readingsValues = readingsValue.objects.all()

    return render(request, "meters/index.html",
                  {
                   "readingsValues": readingsValues,})
```

And for the template a simple for loop should be sufficient

```
<table>     
    ...
      {% for readingsValue in readingsValues %}         
        {{ readingsValue.readingsValue }}
        {{ readingsValue.meter.meterName }}
        {{ readingsValue.meter.meterType.meterType }}
        {{ readingsValue.readingDate.date }}
      {% endfor %}     
    ...
  </table>
```

And please in models.py change "Zaehler" and "Ablesedatum" with the actual names of the models

Comment: You shou use `select_related` and `prefetch_related` when querying all the data.

Comment: with just using the for-loop I have many times the readingsDate.date in the headline and as well the meter.meterName. But as a table, I just want those values once as row or column headline and the readingsValue I want correctly placed in the corresponding field. This is the trouble I have